# Rancher 2.5.7 - Monitoring - listening port 8080 failed listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, amazon-eks, rancher

In a `Rancher` deployment (via `Helm 3` on an `EKS` cluster, version `2.5.7`), installation of `Rancher's Monitoring` failed. The `rancher-monitoring-operator` Pod in the `cattle-monitoring-system` Namespace goes in the `crashLoopBackoff` with the following error in the logs:

```
ts=2021-03-31T13:30:59.0269739Z caller=main.go:209 msg="Starting Prometheus Operator version '0.38.1'."
listening port 8080 failedlisten tcp :8080: bind: address already in use
```

The Monitoring version: `9.4.203`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a port conflict with the `node-local-dns` daemonset. After changing the port of the `node-local-dns` to something other than `8080`, the issue resolved.